# How to avoid these errors while fetching api in python

Tags: python, api

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/2807435?apikey=secret')
print(response)
x = response.json()
y = json.dumps(x)
z = json.loads(y)
a = z['WeatherText']
print(a)
yt = input("Press Enter to close")
```

This code is for retrieving weather data from accuweather. When I run the file, i get an error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

A sample image of the initial json file is:
[This image is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGu0h.png)

Please help me with the error

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: btw, I think you just need `x`. `y` and `z` are just duplicating what you already have in `x`.

Comment: Looks like `z` is a list of `dict`s, you can't index a list with a string, you must extract the `dict` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need `x`, but you also need to recognise that it is a list:

```py
a = x[0]['WeatherText']
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `z` is a `list` of `dict`. Therefore you need to go to the first position by:

```py
a = z[0]['WeatherText']
```